# I have downloaded pyinstaller, but when I try to convert the python files, it says [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, pyinstaller

I installed pyinstaller through python -m pip install command. For a reason, pip is not in my path so that's how I did it. Then, it downloads pyinstaller and it gives me a warning that it's not in the path.

I ignore it and proceed to transform the directory where my project is. I wait a few moments and then if shows me this error message:

[the cmd window error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiqCe.png)

```
C:\Users\dhiaa>pyinstaller echecs
88 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
89 INFO: Python: 3.8.1
89 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
92 INFO: wrote C:\Users\dhiaa\echecs.spec
93 INFO: UPX is not available.
95 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\dhiaa', 'C:\\Users\\dhiaa']
96 INFO: checking Analysis
96 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
96 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
100 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
111 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5848 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
5850 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\dhiaa\\lib'
9865 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
10167 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
10172 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\dhiaa\python.exe
10332 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\dhiaa\echecs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dhiaa\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dhiaa\echecs.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['echecs'],
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 416, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 249, in run_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname)
  File "c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1391, in run_script
    with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\dhiaa\\echecs' 
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have a folder containing all my python files, it's not only one python file.

I used git on the main file of my project. Could it affect its accesibility? I also tried just to copy paste the entire project to some other places and the same permission error appears in cmd (even when in admin mode).

Comment: Errors only as text, please

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it again in a CMD opened as administrator?

Can you find **c:\users\dhiaa\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py** on disk?

Comment: Yes I found that file.